# Installing extension parse error

Tags: magento2, php, error

I am getting this error after executing the follow commands in terminal (os x)

```
php bin/magento module:enable WeltPixel_Backend --clear-static-content
php bin/magento module:enable WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider --clear-static-content 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I've installed all the right files in the right folders...
But whenever I execute one of these commands I get the following error:

```
Parse error: parse error in /Applications/magento-2.1.2-0/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

I am using PHP 5.5.31

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:1**

Splat Operator is not working on Php version 5.5.31. so Upgrading your PHP version should fix the error.Upgrade it to **5.6** or **Php7**

**Solution:2**

Remove **var/generation , var/cache and var/page_cache** folders

first you need to try : **setup:di:compile** command it will compile whole code and generate the factory and other var directory again.

**To be summrised follow below command sequence :**

1. **setup:di:compile**
2. **php bin/magento cache:clean**
3. **php bin/magento module:enable WeltPixel_Backend
   --clear-static-content**
4. **php bin/magento module:enable WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider
   --clear-static-content**
5. **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

Lastly if needed then and then run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**